# Detecting up arrow on first line of contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Let's say we work on two divs presented below.

```
<div contenteditable="true">Header</div>
<div contenteditable="true">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Nunc lobortis erat et rhoncus dictum. Suspendisse luctus
</div>
```

Header and LoremIpsum are two different contenteditable divs. LoremIpsum does not contain line breaks. `overflow-wrap: break-word;` is used for breaking line above.

When I press up arrow on `rhoncus` word want to go one line up and this is default behavior of contenteditable. **However when I press arrow on `amet` word I want to focus Header div.**

Is there some way to detect these two situations and handle them differently?

Right now I move to another div only when:

`evt.keyCode === Key.arrowUp && window.getSelection().anchorOffset === 0`

but it requires additional arrow click on first line so cursor goes to start of the line before focusing another div.

Comment: Please format your code so it is presented properly: Either start with 4 spaces or wrap code in ``.. Or use the icon with brackets `<>`.

Comment: did you find a solution to this @julian rubin?

Comment: No, I abandoned pet project :P

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think to do this is to check the value of the current `textContent` at the cursor point, *after* a `keyup` event occurs.

When you're going **up**, this is going to be an empty string (once properly trimmed) and on this basis you can place the focus on the previous `contenteditable` element.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-gates-m0ntw

```
const editableElements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");
const itemLength = editableElements.length;

const createKeyUpEvent = i => () => {
  const selection = document.getSelection();
  const node = selection.anchorNode;
  const text = node.textContent.slice(0, selection.focusOffset).trim();

  // If there is text, do nothing
  if (text) {
    return;
  }

  const previousElement = editableElements[(i - 1) % itemLength];
  previousElement.focus();
};

editableElements.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener("keyup", createKeyUpEvent(i));
});
```

Comment: It works but it introduces strange cursor hop to the beginning of the line. Any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: I don't think the hop is introduced by this solution. The hop is the natural behaviour of the contenteditable box.